# Invariant Violation Invalid hook call / cross-origin error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

So after making this function work I started to create a loop that would give me feedback from the backend after SSR, I wanted to use hooks so I made it a functional component and started to write but the hook (even with nothing in it) is throwing 2 errors. Invalid Hook Call and A cross origin error was thrown.

I tried changing the file name to jsx, moving the file out of the folder I had because there was a second node modules in there (I thought it was using two versions of React), I also read somewhere just to clear local storage and it was just a in development using localhost problem.

***Edit** So i've found that its not even calling the fn: reactToPdfUtils.savePDFNOW(sourceElement, true, undefined, cb) its stopping here

```js
//reactToPdf.js

import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import { savePDF } from '@progress/kendo-react-pdf';
import { drawDOM, exportPDF } from '@progress/kendo-drawing';
var ClassInstancesStore = require('../libs/goggles/reflux/classInstances-store');
var ClassInstancesActions = require('../libs/goggles/reflux/classInstances-actions');



export const savePDFNOW = (sourceElement, willSaveToDB, pageTemplate, cb) => {
    //this hook broke the program as soon as i put it in even with nothing inside
    useEffect(() => {
        //Functionthat gets called after sending the pdf to the backend
        // function onClassInstancesStoreChange(opInfo){
        //     var e = cloneDeep(opInfo);
        //     if (e.op === 'Call::StorePassportPDFToDisk') {
        //         if(e.error){
        //             console.log(e.ret)
        //             setPdf({ pdfErrors: e.ret })
        //         } else {
        //             console.log(e.ret)
        //             setPdf({ inProgress: true })
        //             alert('Successfully created: ' + e.ret.fileName)
        //             // onSubmit()
        //         }
        //     }
        // };
        // let listeners = [];
        // listeners.push(ClassInstancesStore.listen(onClassInstancesStoreChange));
    
        // return function cleanup() {
        //     _.each(listeners, function(listener) {listener();}); //NOTE: destroy listeners
        // }
    
    }, [])

    try {
      //do all the my functions that make my pdf perfect
    } catch (error) {
        //snap something went wrong all my awesome error handling
    }
};






//previewer.jsx
var React = require('react');
var _ = require('underscore');
var reactToPdfUtils = require('../../../../../components/reactToPdf.js');


    handleSave = (sourceElement) => {
        reactToPdfUtils.savePDFNOW(sourceElement, true, undefined, cb)
        function cb(sendDataContent){
            if(sendDataContent.err){
                console.log(sendDataContent.message)
            } else {
                console.log('sucess')
            }
        }
    };
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of the code is that the function `handleSave` will call the external hook `savePDFNOW`. If this is what happens, then this will break regardless of the useEffect logic.

The reason for that is that hooks that are extracted outside of the component require their name to start with `use`

So to allow the hook to run you change its name to `useSavePDFNOW`.

That being said, I believe this is not a valid use case for useEffect, think of useEffect as componentDidMount/Update. This is relevant to component render cycle rather than event listeners. It makes more sense to do away with the useEffect and keep it a regular function.

A few more things, if you are using the latest react version you don't need to import react. Also it's recommended to use const/let instead of var as well.